# Read error: #<Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.> in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, radrails

i am getting below message in my log while running my ruby application with firefox & IE8 .
Is any one got same message while running ruby application?

```
Fri Aug 20 18:18:17 +0100 2011: Read error: #<Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.>
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:137:in `write'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel/http_response.rb:137:in `write'
    C:/Development/Aptana/cloud_community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:75:in `process'
    C:/Development/Aptana/cloud_community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/file.rb:83:in `each'
    C:/Development/Aptana/cloud_community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/file.rb:81:in `open'
    C:/Development/Aptana/cloud_community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/file.rb:81:in `each'
    C:/Development/Aptana/cloud_community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:74:in `process'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mswin32-60/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
    C:/Development/Aptana/cloud_community/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
    C:/Development/Aptana/cloud_community/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    C:/Development/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    ./script/server:3
    -e:2:in `load'
    -e:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the official Rails installer instead of InstantRails and see if that solves your issue? http://rubyonrails.org/download